# OpenCV C++ Tracking API

Tags: c++, opencv

I've built OpenCV from source along with the contrib modules. But when I include the tracking module with:

```
#include <opencv2/tracking.hpp>
```

or

```
#include <opencv2/tracking/tracking.hpp>
```

or

```
#include <opencv2/video/tracking.hpp>
```

and then try to use a tracker like this:

```
cv::Ptr<cv::Tracker> tracker;
```

I get an error saying that "Tracker is not a member of 'cv'".

What is the proper way to include the tracking API and how can I troubleshoot possible installation errors?

Comment: The documentation seems to say `#include <opencv2/tracking/tracker.hpp>` is correct: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d0a/classcv_1_1Tracker.html

Comment: I think the include paths in OpenCV are Confusing, not only this tracking file but almost all the OpenCV files are like this. And at the same OpenCV needs to clean up the Confusing path names, e.g: opencv2, this `2` leads to thinking that it is OpenCV2.x.x version so there can be opencv3, opencv4, etc..., so it will be better to only use the name opencv and it is OK e.g: opencv/xxx/xxxx.hpp

Comment: First and second includes are right. The problem is outside of source file.

Comment: @Nuzhny any idea how to identify the problem?

Comment: Do you can compile samples from opencv? They are working? Do you use cmake and find_package for building yours project? Are you sure than opencv_tracking module was compiled?