# Using OpenCv c++ tracking api from contrib library

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, raspberry-pi

I am using the OpenCV 3.2.0 packages from the raspberry pi repos. I can't seem to find a way to use the tracking api from the contrib library. The `libopencv-contrib-dev` and `libopencv-contrib-3.2.0` packages are installed but when including `<opencv2/tracking.hpp>` in my project I get the following error:

```
/home/pi/wippe/src/wippe.cpp:4:10: fatal error: opencv2/tracking.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <opencv2/tracking.hpp>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)
project (wippe)

set (CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT "-lpthread")
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pthread -std=c++17")
set (CMAKE_HAVE_THREADS_LIBRARY 1)
set (CMAKE_USE_PTHREADS_INIT 1)
set (THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)

find_package (PkgConfig REQUIRED)
find_package (OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package (raspicam REQUIRED)

find_library (wiringPi_LIB wiringPi)

include_directories (${OpenCV_INDCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable (wippe src/wippe.cpp)

target_link_libraries (wippe ${raspicam_LIBS})
target_link_libraries (wippe ${raspicam_CV_LIBS})
target_link_libraries (wippe ${OpenCV_LIBS};tracking;opencv_tracking)
target_link_libraries (wippe ${wiringPi_LIBS})
```

I already saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55483682/opencv-c-tracking-api) and took a look at the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/de/df6/contrib_2modules_2tracking_2include_2opencv2_2tracking_8hpp.html) which says that `<opencv2/tracking.hpp>` includes `<opencv2/tracking/tracker.hpp>` but never the less tried out all combinations I could come up with.

Do I have to include the OpenCV contrib libs in a different way or explicitly link the dirs? I really don't have any clue.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to build OpenCV with extra modules in order to use the tracking api.

You can do so following these steps :

[How to build OpenCV with extra modules](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib)

Comment: I know I can build opencv from source but I would like to avoid that if possible. So are the raspberry pi packages from the official repo just not functional, and if so, why does the contrib package even exist? Are there prebuilt binaries somewhere?

Comment: They are not included in the main build of OpenCV as they are "new" modules that are not well tested yet. Once the modules are tested and are up to a certain standard they are pushed to the main build. This might be useful but I have never used it so I cannot confirm whether it is usable compared to opencv-contrib https://pypi.org/project/opencv-contrib-python/.

Comment: The `libopencv-contrib3.2` package's info says: ```Description: computer vision contrlib library
 This package contains the OpenCV (Open Computer Vision) opencv_contrib runtime
 libraries. This package contain following contrlib libraries:
 .
   - aruco
   - bgsegm
   - bioinspired
   - ccalib
   - dnn
   - dpm
   - fuzzy
   - hdf
   - line_descriptor
   - optflow
   - plot
   - reg
   - saliency
   - stereo
   - structured_light
   - rgbd
   - surface_matching
   - tracking
   - datasets
   - text
   - face
   - ximgproc
   - xobjdetect
   - xphoto
 .```

Comment: But I can't seem to find the modules listed anywhere in the system, where as the default opencv modules are in `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf`. These packages seem to be useless.